# Error using label tag in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

I was going through Railscasts video on jquery and came across some code. I'm making a todo list app . Here is my jquery code :

lists.js

```
$(function () {
 $('.edit_task input[type=submit]').remove();
 $('.edit_task  input[type=checkbox]').click(function () {
   console.log(this);
  });
});
```

I have a list/show.html.erb file :

```
<h3>Unfinished Tasks</h3>
<div class="tasks" id="incomplete_tasks">
  <% @list.tasks.incomplete.each do |task| %>
      <%= form_for [current_user, @list, task], remote: true do |f| %>
          <%= f.label :completed, class: 'checkbox' do %>
          <%= f.check_box :completed %>
          <%= task.description %>
      <% end %>
      <%= f.submit "Update" %>        <!--We hide this button in jquery-->
  <% end %>
  <% end %>
</div>
<h3>Finished Tasks</h3>
<div class="tasks" id="completed_tasks">
  <% @list.tasks.completed.each do |task| %>
      <%= form_for [current_user, @list, task], remote: true do |f| %>
         <%= f.label :completed, class: 'checkbox' do %>
          <%= f.check_box :completed %>
          <%= task.description %>
      <% end %>
      <%= f.submit "Update" %>        <!--We hide this button in jquery-->
  <% end %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

So, this produces the following html code. :

```
<div class="tasks" id="incomplete_tasks">
  <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/users/4/lists/12/tasks/23" class="edit_task"     data-remote="true" id="edit_task_23" method="post">
      <label class="checkbox" for="task_completed">
          <input name="task[completed]" type="hidden" value="0" /><input id="task_completed" name="task[completed]" type="checkbox" value="1" />
          Read for exam
     </label> 
     <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Update" />        <!--We hide this button in jquery-->
 </form>
   <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/users/4/lists/12/tasks/24" class="edit_task"     data-remote="true" id="edit_task_24" method="post">
      <label class="checkbox" for="task_completed">
          <input name="task[completed]" type="hidden" value="0" /><input id="task_completed" name="task[completed]" type="checkbox" value="1" />
          Eat healthy food
     </label> 
     <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Update" />        <!--We hide this button in jquery-->
  </form>
```

If you notice, you see that the

```
 <input name="task[completed]" type="hidden" value="0" /><input id="task_completed" name="task[completed]" type="checkbox" value="1" />
```

has same id="task_completed" for both the forms . So when I click on text in the second list(form), the first form gets selected. How do I get around this ? Is there a certain "Rails way" to do this ? Please help me .

Edit: So the problem is that both the inputs in different forms have same id which is automatically created by rails using this code

```
              <%= f.check_box :completed %>
```

So, How can I override the id creation in rails so that I have unique id for each form/input tag ?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have two items on the same page that have the same id, use a class instead. Second you may find scoping your css selectors may help.

```
$("#incomplete_tasks .task_completed").click(function(){

});
```

Comment: Thank you ..But how do I override the default id value in form helpers in Rails.

Comment: Its great you got it, but if someone comes across this and doesn't know, its 

    <%= f.check_box :completed, :id => "your-id" %>